# Using same session ID for every user?

Tags: asp.net

How can one exploit the scenario of using same session ID for every user with changing customer ID...assume my web application is a ecommerce application.

Is there any possibility to exploit. Im using asp.net.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The framework should make it impossible to share sessions. Is this a vulnerability you've discovered in your code? If so please share it and explain the steps to reproduce it. Or are you asking for tips on hacking? I don't think the community here is the right one for that.

Comment: Thanks ADyson, all i wanted to know is how vulnerable it could be and are there any ways an attacker can leverage this scenario coz i've found this while im a doing a pentest on my own website which was developed by a 3rd party vendor. I can work along with dev's to mitigate this vulnerability but before i need to convey them how one can exploit it.

Comment: There shouldn't be a way and I'm not aware of a way. If you've found a way then surely you know how to explain it to your devs? P.s. it wasn't related to static variables was it, because _those_ can be shared across sessions (but they're not part of the Session object).